# Setting a child attribute from parent in FactoryGirl

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, factory-bot

How do you set a dependent attribute that depends on in FactoryGirl?

```
FactoryGirl.define do
  factory :line_item do
    quantity 1
    price 30 # I want price to come from the product association: self.product.price

    cart
    order
    product
  end
end
```

I tried this but it didn't work:

```
  factory :line_item do |f|
    f.quantity 1

    f.cart
    f.order
    f.product
    after_build do |line_item|
      line_item.price = line_item.product.price
    end
  end
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try something like this:

```
FactoryGirl.define do   
  factory :line_item do
    quantity 1
    price { product.price }

    cart
    order
    product   
  end 
end
```

Comment: Does the order of the attributes matter? Here it doesn't look very natural that the 'product' attribute is declared after 'price'